# How to paint using an Image

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a game where two users have to colour in the screen and the user with the most colour on screen wins. I'm currently stuck on how to make an image leave behind the paint. The code below allows the user to paint. I attempted to turn the image into a bitmap and have it follow the touch but I wasn't able to implement it. Any help appreciated

```
public class PaintView extends View {

    public LayoutParams params;
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint brush = new Paint();
    

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);

       

        brush.setAntiAlias(true);
        brush.setColor(Color.RED);
        brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        brush.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        brush.setStrokeWidth(120f);  // size of brush adjust accordingly

        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        postInvalidate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawPath(path, brush,);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```